# Use awk to list all values seen in a column

Tags: awk, csv

I have a large data file with genetic information in it:

```
head Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.93.chr.onlyGene.gff3
1       ensembl gene    100000637       100000739       .       -       .       ID=ENSG00000202259;Name=RNU6-1318P;Name=ENSG00000202259
1       ensembl gene    101133153       101133339       .       +       .       ID=ENSG00000252765;Name=RF00424;Name=ENSG00000252765
1       ensembl gene    10163268        10163374        .       +       .       ID=ENSG00000201746;Name=RNU6-828P;Name=ENSG00000201746
1       ensembl gene    101728642       101728737       .       -       .       ID=ENSG00000252530;Name=RNU6-965P;Name=ENSG00000252530
1       ensembl gene    101859851       101859957       .       +       .       ID=ENSG00000252717;Name=RNU6-352P;Name=ENSG00000252717
1       ensembl gene    10298966        10299072        .       +       .       ID=ENSG00000199562;Name=RNU6-37P;Name=ENSG00000199562
1       ensembl gene    10306465        10306757        .       +       .       ID=ENSG00000264501;Name=RN7SL731P;Name=ENSG00000264501
1       ensembl gene    103523562       103523879       .       +       .       ID=ENSG00000222069;Name=RN7SKP285;Name=ENSG00000222069
1       ensembl gene    10616836        10617115        .       +       .       ID=ENSG00000243267;Name=RN7SL614P;Name=ENSG00000243267
1       ensembl gene    109100193       109100612       .       +       .       ID=ENSG00000278249;Name=SCARNA2;Name=ENSG00000278249

tail Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.93.chr.onlyGene.gff3
Y       havana  gene    9740584 9758476 .       +       .       ID=ENSG00000212855;Name=TTTY2;Name=ENSG00000212855
Y       havana  gene    9753156 9774289 .       -       .       ID=ENSG00000129845;Name=TTTY1;Name=ENSG00000129845
Y       havana  gene    9801153 9813245 .       +       .       ID=ENSG00000224075;Name=TTTY22;Name=ENSG00000224075
Y       havana  gene    9813315 9817513 .       +       .       ID=ENSG00000228379;Name=AC010891.1;Name=ENSG00000228379
Y       havana  gene    9831418 9846696 .       -       .       ID=ENSG00000229208;Name=RBMY2NP;Name=ENSG00000229208
Y       havana  gene    9868462 9868702 .       -       .       ID=ENSG00000274445;Name=AC006986.1;Name=ENSG00000274445
Y       havana  gene    9869664 9870781 .       +       .       ID=ENSG00000231874;Name=TSPY18P;Name=ENSG00000231874
Y       havana  gene    9905595 9908139 .       -       .       ID=ENSG00000187657;Name=TSPY13P;Name=ENSG00000187657
Y       havana  gene    9910798 9911962 .       +       .       ID=ENSG00000239225;Name=TTTY23;Name=ENSG00000239225
Y       havana  gene    9951553 9959423 .       +       .       ID=ENSG00000234950;Name=RBMY2OP;Name=ENSG00000234950
```

Column 2 shows the source of the data (which biological database the gene is registered on).

Is there any way to show all of the values in column 2, but only once each? As in `ensembl, havana, foo, bar`, and if possible the number of lines that contain each of these values?

Comment: @muru it does actually! Not sure how I missed that :/

Answer (score 2):

you can do it all using **AWK**

```
awk '{A[$2]++}END{for(i in A)print i,A[i]}' Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.93.chr.onlyGene.gff3
```

The output will be

```
ensembl 10
havana 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try piping the output of `awk` (to select the second column) through `sort` and (as noted by @αғsнιη) `uniq` for its `--count` option, like in

```
awk '{print $2}' Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.93.chr.onlyGene.gff3 | sort | uniq -c
```